# Is there any way to list what lot types do or do not exist in my current neighborhood?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have many expansion packs installed for The Sims 3. I would like to have as many [lot types](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Lot_assignment) in my neighborhood as possible, but crosschecking all lots with all available lot types seems like a pretty extreme grind.

Is there any way to do this without writing down lists of what lot types my neighborhood has and which are available and comparing them?

Comment: Sadly I am not aware of any!

Answer (score 1):

There are none, least not from my experience.